# Move line (2 GPS coordinates) towards other GPS coordinate

Tags: google-maps, math, google-maps-api-3, gps

So I have a line made up of two GPS points (lat, lng) (the red line in the picture), I have another GPS point (marker on the picture).
I want to move the red line to the marker every 2 meters, is it possible ?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is definitively possible. I would suggest to do this in three steps:

1. Transform the coordinates into a UTM coordinate system. This can be done with [proj4js](https://github.com/proj4js/proj4js) for example.
2. Move the coordinates 2 meters into the desired direction.
3. Transform the coordinates back into your original coordinate system (probably WGS84 if you are using GPS data).

I would also recommend you to read a bit about coordinate systems. WGS84 uses latitude-longitude coordinates. This makes it very difficult to move the coordinates in meters. Therefore, you have to transform the coordinates into a coordinate system which uses meters and allows such operations.

Comment: what is the best way to move 2 meters UTM coordinate system? @mrunde

Comment: You should maybe ask this question in this community as you will find more experts there: http://gis.stackexchange.com/